# Redefine xsd element

Tags: xml, xsd

I am trying to redefine an element definition contained in an [external xsd](http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd)  (that I cannot modify) which looks like this:

```
<xsd:element name="view-controller">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:attribute name="path" type="xsd:string" use="required" />
        <xsd:attribute name="view-name" type="xsd:string" />
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```

This defines elements such as:

```
<mvc:view-controller path="/path" view-name="server/view/etc" />
```

**How do I extend it so that I can create elements with 2 additional attributes (foo and bar)?**
See this example below for the end result I need:

```
<mvc:view-controller path="/path" view-name="server/view/etc" foo="stuff" bar="more stuff" />
```

What I tried:

```
<xsd:redefine schemaLocation="http://www.domain.org/schema/correct-path.xsd">
    <xsd:simpleType name="view-controller">
        <xsd:complexContent>
            <xsd:extension base="view-controller">
                <xsd:attribute name="foo" type="xsd:string" />
                <xsd:attribute name="bar" type="xsd:string" />
            </xsd:extension>
        </xsd:complexContent>
    </xsd:simpleType>
</xsd:redefine>
```

However this doesn't work.
I cannot seem to find any resource detailing how to redefine an `xsd:element` containing attributes, which I believe is the problem here.

Please comment if more info is required.

Comment: This is really confusing. Is this a question about Spring MVC, XML Schema, or Visual Studio? It's can't be all three.

Comment: The above schema is taken from a spring mvc xml, I added that tag in case somebody had to modify it exactly as I have to now. Visual studio is merely telling me that the above is wrong, but I'm assuming anything else would have highlighted the same errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have a complexContent inside a simpleType, it doesn't make sense.

Also, the only things you can redefine are : simpleType, complexType, group, attributeGroup. So you can't redefine an element. You could change its type only if it has a named type, which doesn't seem to be the case in your example.

See http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-0/#Redefine for more info.

Comment: Still new with xml schemas so I knew I made mistakes there - but are you saying that given an element defined with 2 attributes, I can no longer add any attribute?

Comment: In this case, because the element type is not named in the original schema, you can't redefine it as you were hoping. But what is your goal anyway ? I mean, if you want to create valid documents for this mvc schema, you can't add attributes (this is what the schema is for, and this schema does not allow additional attributes for the view-controller element). But if you don't care about it, you could copy this schema file and change it - and also change the namespace to avoid confusion.

Comment: My goal was extending the xml so that my application could have some required additional data that the original application doesn't need. Hard to understand why I can't *add* data, I can see why would attributes be protected from deletion tho. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

@Razor, you mean you don't want to modify the existing xsd but want to create one more xsd which alters element properties??

if that is the case then I think its almost impossible! errors like `definition already exists`trouble ..

Comment: It's not that I don't want, I can't as it's mantained by a third party. Pretty sure that `xsd:redefine` does what I need here, but I do not know what's the correct syntax.